# Target the found element in .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace a number of name and id attributes on cloned html elements and wrote a simple replace function that replaces all the numbers in the attribute strings.

I use .find to find an element in a div and then use .attr() to replace the name or id but I want to use the found element as $(this) or anything else.

So how can I target the element that I found by calling .find()?

This is what I want to use or something similar

```
newField.find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name', replaceNumbersinStringTo($(this).attr('name'), index+1));
```

The problem lies in the $(this) that doesnt contain in this case the hidden input.

Replace function

```
function replaceNumbersinStringTo(string, replaceTo)
{
    return string.replace(/\d+/g,replaceTo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `this`. `this` inside the function call refers to the context of the function where the code is present not the `newField` element.

```
newField.find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name', function (i, name) {
    return replaceNumbersinStringTo(name, index + 1)
});
```

or

```
newField.find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name', replaceNumbersinStringTo(newField.attr('name'), index+1));
```

Comment: The bottom one was something I thought of but for some reason I didn't want to use it, maybe because it feels repetitive.

I'm gonna go with your first solution, it looks exactly like what I was asking for in this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to declare your found element in a variable.

```
var found = newField.find('input[type="hidden"]');
found.attr('name', replaceNumbersinStringTo(found.attr('name'), index+1));
```

This essentially replaces your `$(this)` function, which also means you can do more things on your found object without asking jQuery to create and return a new jQuery object.

Comment: Possible solution, I don't need the found attribute at all after the replace so storing it feels a bit meh to me. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
newField.find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('name', replaceNumbersinStringTo($(this).attr('name'), i+1);
});
```

I'm not sure how you use "index" or i in my example, so that might need to be modified a bit to fit your needs.

Alternatively I would say consider using a template and rendering elements that way if you are going to be doing this cloning operation a lot. You could essentially put tokens into your template where the name attribute goes, and then just pass the appropriate value in when you render the template. Examples here: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I've thought about the each but it felt weird because there is always only one element found. Thanks!

Comment: @Jebble The find() function in jquery is written to return a list of matches, so it shouldn't feel weird that you use each() on the results. The alternative is to get the first item from the list using .eq(0), assign it to a variable, then do what you want to with the variable instead of using 'this' to reference the element.